# Retrieve specific row in json WebResponse c#

Tags: c#, json

i am trying to retrieve specific row in a json request through WebResponse method but is currently not working out. I am converting a wav files audio to text. It works good and converts it well but i am getting output rows: RecognitionStatus, Duration, Display, Offset. The only row i want outputed to the textbox is the "Display" row where the audio to text is converted to.

the json format looks like this and i am trying to get the "Display" row only.

```
{
  "RecognitionStatus": "Success",
  "Offset": 22500000,
  "Duration": 21000000,
  "NBest": [{
    "Confidence": 0.941552162,
    "Lexical": "find a funny movie to watch",
    "ITN": "find a funny movie to watch",
    "MaskedITN": "find a funny movie to watch",
    "Display": "Find a funny movie to watch."
  }]
}
```

this is my current code so far.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        string ResponseString;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/dictation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=simple");
        request.SendChunked = true;
        request.Accept = @"application/json;text/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.ContentType = @"audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000";
        request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = "hidden";

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"G:\Microsoft Visual Studio Projects\SpeechRecognitionFormsTestUpdaterad\SpeechRecognitionForms\bin\Debug\Logs\log 24-2.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] buffer = null;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                /*
                * Read 1024 raw bytes from the input audio file.
                */

                buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(1024, (int)fs.Length))];
                while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                // Flush
                requestStream.Flush();
            }
        }
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                ResponseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                MyObject obj = (MyObject)js.Deserialize(ResponseString, typeof(MyObject));
                textBox1.Text = ResponseString;
            }
            //textBox1.Text = ResponseString;
        }
```

Comment: Json.Net is much preferred over `JavaScriptSerializer`, try to use that?

Comment: Ye i am looking at it but just dont get how to retrieve that specific row.

Comment: If you only have a single item in `NBest`, use `obj.NBest[0].Display` otherwise loop through `NBest`

Comment: Thank you! obj.DisplayText; worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `NBest` will be a collection. You'll have to iterate to get each value of `Display`.

You can retrieve the value of `Display` like:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    ResponseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    MyObject obj = (MyObject)js.Deserialize(ResponseString, typeof(MyObject));
    textBox1.Text = ResponseString;
    foreach (var nb in obj.NBest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nb.Display);
    }
}
```

Or in case you always get a single `NBest` object you can retrieve it like:

```
if (obj.NBest.Count == 1)
{
    string display = obj.NBest[0].Display;
}
```

**Update:**

Following are the classes I deserialized OP's JSON into:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string RecognitionStatus { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public List<Nbest> NBest { get; set; }
}

public class Nbest
{
    public float Confidence { get; set; }
    public string Lexical { get; set; }
    public string ITN { get; set; }
    public string MaskedITN { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hey, i tried but it but doesnt output "Display" only. It outputs the same as before. my object class looks like this.         public class MyObject
        {
            public string DisplayText;
        } and i dont know if that is right, Because it doesnt have any connection with the webresponse what so ever

Comment: @Weirdrandom
Can you share the classes that you are trying to deserialize this JSON into?

Comment: Hey! , yes it worked now. I just did obj.DisplayText and it worked! :D

Answer (score 1):

Without need to deserialize to custom types you can use native JSON.Net objects:

```
string thejson = @"
{
  ""RecognitionStatus"": ""Success"",
  ""Offset"": 22500000,
  ""Duration"": 21000000,
  ""NBest"": [{
    ""Confidence"": 0.941552162,
    ""Lexical"": ""find a funny movie to watch"",
    ""ITN"": ""find a funny movie to watch"",
    ""MaskedITN"": ""find a funny movie to watch"",
    ""Display"": ""Find a funny movie to watch.""
  }]
}";

var jobj = JObject.Parse(thejson);
JArray arr = jobj["NBest"] as JArray;
foreach (JToken jt in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(jt["Display"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your response is only json why don't you try to convert it to an deserialize object using 
[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)'s deserialize method. It will give you access for specific property from response.
You can use this [JsonToC#](http://json2csharp.com) which will give you object from json string.

Or just `obj.NBest[index]`will give u specific record.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` also gives access to the properties.

Comment: He just need to use obj.NBest[index] to get specific record.

Answer (score 0):

Faizan's answer is on point and it will give you what you want.
However if you don't want to be bothered with creating an object to deserialize your response to. You can make use of the dynamic keyword, likewise:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    ResponseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(ResponseString);
    textBox1.Text = obj["NBest"][0]["Display"];
}
```